# Passing Classes to All Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I have Datatables Drawing a Shopping List for me with results from a MySQL database. When I go to the next page all classes drop which have been pulled through the MySQL database, so they can vary from one row to another.

```
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    fnDrawCallback : function() {

    }        
});
```

I know that `fnDrawCallback` is needed for what I'm trying to do, but not sure what would work.

```
            if(self::Account("donatepoints", Session("userid")) >= $row['cost']) {
                $purchase = '<button class="btn btn-info item"
                data-toggle="modal" 
                data-id="'.$row['itemid'].'"                        
                data-name="'.$row['itemname'].'"
                data-cost="'.$row['cost'].'"
                data-rewardtype = "'.$row['rewardtype'].'"
                data-target="#char-modal">Purchase <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>';
            }
            else { 
            $purchase = '<button class="btn btn-warning donate"
            >Get Points <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>';
            }
```

Is an example of what's called from the MySQL database. And my Jquery at the end of the page

```
 $(".item").click(function(){
     $(".itemname").html($(this).data("name"));
     $("#purchaseform").html("<input type='hidden' name='rewardtype' id='rewardtype' value='" + $(this).data("rewardtype") + "'><input type='hidden' name='itemid' id='itemid' value='" + $(this).data("id") + "'><input type='hidden' name='cost' id='cost' value='" + $(this).data("cost") + "'>");
   });
 $(".donate").click(function() {
     location.href = "/purchase";
 })
```

So as you can see it's not something I can manually redraw when the user goes to the next page, if anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? What are you actually trying to do?